# Can someone help me optimize this "request prime numbers" PHP Function

Tags: php, performance, function, optimization

i`m having trouble optimizing the performance of this PHP function, witch is supposed to return the first $n number of primes requested. The request is made through a form, and when i request the first 10 000 prime numbers the execution exceeds the 30 sec. time limit and returns a fatal error. I would be very thankful if you give me tips on how can i make the function better.

```
function fprimes($n){
    //The Primes Array
    $history = array(2,3);
    //number to be tested
    $item = 4;
    //Set indicator for primacy
    $build = 1;
    if($n == 0){
        echo "No primes requested!";
    }
    elseif($n == 1){
        echo "The first prime number is: ".$n;
    }
    elseif($n == 2){
        echo "The first ".$n." prime numbers are: </br> 1 </br> 2";
    }
    elseif($n > 2){
        while((count($history)+1)<$n){
            foreach($history as $prime){
                if($item%$prime!=0){
                    $build++;
                }
            }
            if((count($history)+1)==$build){
                $history[]=$item;
            }
            $build = 1;
            $item++;
        }
        echo "The first prime ".$n." numbers are: </br>1";
        foreach($history as $printPrime){
            echo "</br>".$printPrime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off topic: 1 is not a prime number.

Comment: I`m sorry, but it`s just the way i was teached :) Every time that the question is 1 a prime or not came along, teachers fallen into a religious debate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One super easy optimization I see is that you can do:

```
$item += 2;
```

Because even numbers are never prime (except for 2).

---

One non-prime related optimization is to keep track of the number of primes you have found instead of reevaluating `count($history)` every time.

Comment: `count` shouldn't be any slower than reading a variable, it's just a header field in the array, it doesn't actually have to count linearly.

Comment: Another optimization is to stop checking history when it's greater than `sqrt($item)`.

Comment: Sometimes obvious things are the hardest to see :) Thank you :)

Comment: You could also add a `break` when `$item % prime == 0`: `if($item%$prime!=0){$build++;} else {break;}` - as for sure this will not be a prime if it divides.

Comment: Yea I'm pretty sure the `foreach` is bad since you only need to find _one_ counter example. I assumed the code did that but I guess it doesn't. Well spotted. This also explains why `+= 2` has a _huge_ impact on performance.

Comment: Yep, with these adjustments my machine nailed the 11 000 prime (being 116 443) within the 30 sec. limit.